# Remove parent folder but keep subfolder intact?

Tags: bash, 22.04, mv

Hullo all, i've seen this question asked before but I am hoping for a different solution.

I have this folder structure;
/home/radamand/folder1/folder2

folder1 ONLY contains folder2, however folder2 contains about 6 terrabytes of files.
Is there a way to remove folder 1, but retain folder2 such that the result would look like this?

/home/radamand/folder2

The previous solution I saw suggested moving all of the files up one dir, then deleting folder2, but this would take quite a while with 6 TB of files, is there another way?

Answer (score 1):

Move folder2 to wanted new position and remove folder1 (which now must be empty):

```
mv /home/radamand/folder1/folder2 /home/radamand/folder2
rmdir /home/radamand/folder1/
```

should do it, I think.

Comment: Okay, but that's still trying to move 6TB of files, which I was hoping to avoid

Comment: That is only moving one directory.entry, not the entire data ... as long as source and destination is within same filesystem.

Comment: Well, I actually tried this and it just started copying files over, one at a time...